# Using the PCT in Matlab with (separate) multiple sessions/windows open

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

On my Mac, I am able to open two Matlab windows at once, which allows me to run two separate scripts simultaneously. Recently, I have converted each of these files in order to take advantage of the Parallel Computing toolbox (e.g. change for loops to par for, etc).

Suppose in windows A and B I am running scripts A and B respectively using parallel computing functions.  Now suppose that in window B, I close the parallel pool (e.g. I type:

```
matlabpool close
```

(or delete(gcp) in the newer versions). Here is my question. If I type this command in window B, what, if anything, would happen to the program running in window A? Is it still taking advantage of the Parallel Computing Toolbox?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: @David Yes, Frequently I get a message along the following "Warning: Found 2 pre-existing parallel job(s) created by matlabpool that are running." This seems to indicate it is still running on the other window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pools opened by the separate MATLAB windows are completely independent - however they are backed by "job" objects stored on disk. This storage location is *by default* shared by all MATLABs on your machine, and this can lead to warnings about pre-existing pool jobs. You can ignore these warnings - or, if you really want, you can set up each MATLAB to use its own storage location, like this:

```
d = tempname(); % get a temporary location
mkdir(d);
cluster = parallel.cluster.Local('JobStorageLocation', d);
matlabpool(cluster);
```